# Add attribute to every element with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I want to add an attribute `Permenant = yes` to every `<File>` element:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="DATADIR">
            <Directory Id="dir8EB85FD628E9C5D122F0BADE39DDAE35" Name="config" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="AssembliesDataDirGroup">
            <Component Id="cmpCEE154EC3F8D0FF001948410061242D4" Directory="dir8EB85FD628E9C5D122F0BADE39DDAE35" Guid="*">
                <File Id="filBAB615DC969ACFD243D566F889384EAB" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDirectory)\config\jj.options" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp7D1A807E2DEC4CCE0C14E0A26500CED2" Directory="dir8EB85FD628E9C5D122F0BADE39DDAE35" Guid="*">
                <File Id="filB963451E642F947E821629411CBBD719" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDirectory)\config\log4j2.properties" />
            </Component>
            ...
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I am trying the following in my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
            xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl wi">
            
    ..
    ..      
    <xsl:template match="wi:File">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="Permenant">
                <xsl:value-of select="yes"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

But nothing is working. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Updated the xslt

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples of XSLT, sample input, sample output you want and the sample output you get together with any error message, if you get one if nothing is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have:

```
<xsl:attribute name="Permenant">
    <xsl:value-of select="yes"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

is looking for a child element named `yes` which does not exists. To populate the attribute with the text "yes", you need:

```
<xsl:attribute name="Permenant">
    <xsl:value-of select="'yes'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

or just:

```
<xsl:attribute name="Permenant">yes</xsl:attribute>
```

Here you can see it working, after adding the identity transform template: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFuiXXM

---

BTW, that is not how you spell *Permanent*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor then add the attribute `xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"` on the `xsl:template` element or on your `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` element.

Comment: I updated the question, still it isn't working.

Comment: @brunofer42, you have tagged the question as `xslt-2.0` and `xslt-3.0`, therefore I have answered with a suggestion that makes sense in the context of using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor. Which XSLT processor do you use? If you use an XSLT 1.0 processor then my suggestion won't help.